# iterating over length of string variable jinja2

Tags: loops, jinja2

I'm trying to iterate over the length of a string variable in jinja2.

what I have is:

```
<table>
    <tbody>

   {% for i in range(string1|length) %}

  <tr>
      <td>
          test
      </td>
  </tr>

  {% endfor %}

   </tbody>
</table>
```

but when I run the application with flask literally nothing is displayed.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `string1` a variable containing a string, or are you trying to iterate over the length of `string1`?

Comment: it's a variable containing a string

Comment: Then something is wrong with `string1`. I'd suggest outputting `string1|length` and seeing what gets displayed. My guess it would be `0`

Comment: ok it gets displayed as 0. 
I think I need to somehow link the document in which I am writing this with the document that feeds the variables into it.